# How to return the index of the matching row when comparing a matrix to a vector in r

Tags: r

The data are:

```r
a <- matrix(c(1,1,2,2,'a','b','c','d'),4,2)
b <- c(1,'a')
```

So the first row of `a` matches `b`. If I want to return the index of the row in the matrix `a` (which is 1), what code would I apply in r? I tried:

```r
which((a[,1]==b[1])&(a[,2]==b[2])), is there any other option?
```

Answer (score 3):

We can replicate the 'b' by the `row` of 'a' and do an elementwise comparison, then wrap the `which` to get the index

```
which(a == b[row(a)])
```

Note that this gives the index of the element.  If we need the index of row where everything matches.

```
which(rowSums(a == b[col(a)]) == ncol(a))
```

Or

```
 which(a == b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option but with `match`

```
match(list(b),asplit(a,1))
```

or

```
match(asplit(t(b),1),asplit(a,1))
```

or

```
match(as.data.frame(t(t(b))),as.data.frame(t(a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of more options :

```
which(colSums(t(a) != b) == 0)
```

and

```
which(rowSums(sweep(a, 2, b, `!=`)) == 0)
```